# Why does an angular controller clone itself in Jquery UI event functions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to call a function that pushes a new object into templateArea.template (An array of objects).

When this function is called from within Jquery UI Droppable's drop event handler it seems to create it's own version of templateArea to update, rather than the original object.

I would like it to update the original object but am unsure what needs to be done differently.

I understand there are already existing Angular Directives to replace Jquery UI, but I would like to fill the gap in my knowledge as to why this is not working.

```
                // Template Area is an Angular Controller within a directive
                templateArea.template = _.orderBy(templateArea.model.structure, ['order'], ['asc']) 

                // The Function to update Template Area 
                templateArea.addHeader = function () {
                    templateArea.template.push({
                        order: 5,
                        template: "<template-objects-header></template-objects-header>",
                        title: "New Header"
                    })

                    // The logs show that 2 different objects are being updated
                    console.log('templateArea');
                    console.log(templateArea);
                }

                // Jquery UI Droppable Function
                $( ".template-area" ).droppable({
                    accept: ".template-object",
                    drop: function( event, ui ) {
                        templateArea.addHeader();
                    }
                });

                // Test function to see if the same object is being referenced
                templateArea.addHeader();
```

Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: No one has no idea what you are talking about. Create a demo, explain the problem. Otherwise it's too abstract and unlikely to be answered.

Comment: Hi @dfsq, thanks for the reply. Here is the fiddle - https://fiddle.jshell.net/c1dpc7dr/10/. It is working as expected, I thought I was going crazy! I still cannot get it to work in my app though and I cannot replicate the error in the fiddle. I'm afraid I cannot explain the problem anymore because I have no idea what it is. Thanks for your reply anyhow.